# What is the standard way to use a bundle's entities in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I've been trying to learn how to use a bundle in symfony, but ran into some problems making the bundle's entities appear in my database. I finally got it to work by adding the last couple lines to my doctrine.yaml file. However for some reason it seems unlikely that this is the correct way to go about it, giving that it only works if I set the 'is_bundle' property to false, while it's probably supposed to be true, given that it is an entity from a bundle.

What is the correct way to make this entity appear in my database?

My doctrine file:

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    default_connection: default
    connections:
      default:
        # configure these for your database server
        url: '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8mb4
        unix_socket: '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'
        default_table_options:
          charset: utf8mb4
          collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

  orm:
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
      default:
        connection: default
        mappings:
          default:
            is_bundle: false
            type: annotation
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Entity'
            alias: default
          ch_cookie_consent_bundle:
            is_bundle: false
            type: annotation
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/vendor/connectholland/cookie-consent-bundle/Entity'
            prefix: 'ConnectHolland\CookieConsentBundle\Entity'
            alias: ch_cookie_consent_bundle
```

The bundle itself can be found here: https://github.com/ConnectHolland/cookie-consent-bundle

Comment: I know it is counter-intuitive but is_bundle should always be false.  There some bundle specific shortcuts that could be used if set to true, but no one uses them any more.  You used to see things like MyBundle:Entity but everyone just uses the full classname now.  Your config looks correct.

Comment: Did you try to create a migration script? `symfony console make:migration` or `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff`

Answer (score 0):

The `is_bundle` flag instructs the doctrine extension to match the configuration key to the bundle name.

In your case the configuration should be

```yaml
  orm:
    mappings:
      default:
        ...
      CHCookieConsentBundle: # This should match the bundle name (in %kernel.bundles%)
        is_bundle: true
        alias: ch_cookie_consent_bundle
```

All the others configuration keys are optional and auto-detected.